# Autohotkey: Conflict between functions using the same key

Tags: autohotkey

I using a lot the "$" lately, and in my (Spanish) keyboard I must press Shift+4 every time, so I decided to use AutoHotkey to make it faster.
The idea make it faster by using the "ç" key as I don't use it very often.

```
ç::
  Send $; new use of the key
Return
```

This works well but sometimes I do need to write "ç" and "Ç", so I tried to add this

```
!ç::
   Send ç  ; to get the "ç" back in game
Return

+ç::
   Send Ç ;original use of the "ç" key
Return
```

But it's not working (keep sending $, as "ç" is now "$").
I feel like this should be pretty obvious, but still can't find a solution. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Preferred intuitive way: Use `ç::$` instead of command block.

This will re-map the key instead of assigning it a macro. This way is intuitive in AHK scripting because primary and secondary syntax nicely corresponds with primary and secondary intent, i.e.:

1. (primary) completely remapping the key (in AHK this is done without macros)
2. (secondary) adding some macros doing non-standard functionalities

• it does not complicate the thing unnecessarily using `#InputLevel` prioritization

Your complete code after the change:

```
!ç::
   Send ç  ; to get the "ç" back in game
Return

+ç::
   Send Ç ;original use of the "ç" key
Return

; new use of the key
; ### this code has to be b̲e̲l̲o̲w̲ the macros
ç::$
```

**Tested, it works as expected.** (In version 1.1.25.01, 2017-03-05)

Comment: @Oleg – I tested it before posting an answer. It works fine. Do you have any idea why it should not work? If no, maybe you can consider retracting your downvote. Thank you for playing fair.

Comment: You probably only think you did ;). `ç::$` is expanded to `*ç::` and `*ç up::` this will eat all the `ç` hotkeys. If when you tested you put `ç::$` under the other hotkeys, then it explains why it worked for you(the reason is the same it becomes `k-hook` hotkey, and also doesn't eat the other hotkeys). I tested the code you posted in your answer ,it doesn't work and I don't see how it can.

Comment: Might also be a bug in my version. I'm using a rather old one.

Comment: I did, even submitted a [bug report](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=35775). No responses so far. I still don't see how your code can work.

Comment: @Oleg – my bad, I found that tested version was with `ç::$` at the end. I fixed the answer and I apologize for this. I forgot that detail, I recalled it only when I was testing this again. Your detailed explanation was seemingly correct.

Comment: OK, your code now works, but without explaining why it does and OP's doesn't I still don't think this is a good answer.

Comment: @Oleg – sure, but this time user wants help with code, not AHK-specific explanation based on AHK internals. My answer does what the OP requested so it should not be marked as "the answer is not useful".

Comment: Fine, in any case doesn't look like anybody cares but us, even OP is nowhere to be seen. At least add a note saying that it has to be below the other hotkeys and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: Yes, effectively it works, even if I'm not sure why, so I may do the same mistake again... Thanks a lot to both of you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this would be to increase the [#InputLevel](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm)
For your remapped hotkey.

```
#InputLevel 1
ç::
  Send $ ; new use of the key
Return
#InputLevel 0
```

This prevents it from being fired buy the script. A hotkey won't be executed as a result of  `Send` if the `InputLevel` >= [SendLevel](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendLevel.htm). They are both 0 by default.

Actually in this case the problem is not with `SendLevel`(it is not greater than `InputLevel`) but with the `ç` hotkey being registered as a `reg` hotkey, `reg` hotkeys can't distinguish between simulated and real input so it will always be fired.

Using `#UseHook on` instead of setting the input level will also solve the problem. `#InputLevel 1` makes `ç` a `k-hook` key (because all hotkeys with `InputLevel > 0` use the keyboard hook). And in this case this is what's important and not the level itself.

Comment: This worked for me, but the other answer also provides a solution with fewer changes in the code.
Thanks a lot for your explanation, thanks to you, now I understand how the "SendLevel" works and I may use it for other codes.

Comment: @Mosky np, selecting the answer that is most useful to you is exactly what you should do.