# Check if text caret is in a text box in AutoHotkey

Tags: screen-scraping, autohotkey, caret

I want to be able to do different things depending on whether the text caret is in a text box or not.

For example, if the caret is in a text box, then the backspace key functions as normal; but if it isn't then the backspace key maps to Alt+Left (previous page in Chrome).

The following code was all I could come up with:

```
IsInTextBox()
{
    clipboardCache := Clipboard
    Clipboard :=

    ; Try to highlight the character to the left, if something gets highlighted, then we are definitely in a text box.
    Send, +{Left}^c{Right}
    ClipWait, 0.1
    If (Clipboard = "")
    {
        Clipboard := clipboardCache
        Return False
    }
    Else
    {
        Clipboard := clipboardCache
        Return True
    }
}
```

There are 2 problems with this method: First, it won't work if the text caret is at the start of the text box (because there are no characters to the left to be highlighted). Second, you can see the caret moving around and highlighting the character to the left.

Is there is a way to check if the caret is focused on a text box *without* affecting what the user sees?

Comment: Based on later findings by @Oleg, I would like to retract my downvote. Just edit your question so the system will allow me to change my voting.

Answer (score -1):

There is a [comment regarding Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730223/check-if-text-caret-is-in-a-text-box-in-autohotkey/45732323?noredirect=1#comment78426362_45732323) which says that standard way of detection is not possible in Chrome because it does not have classical windows.
So what you want to achieve is not possible by standard AHK-way in Chrome. Maybe you can succeed by writing a Chrome plugin, but I think it is greater mileage to go.

---

In other browsers, you should succeed using this answer I originally wrote:

AutoHotKey forums have an [answer](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/73879-detecting-the-active-textbox-or-tab/):

```
BackSpace::
    ControlGetFocus, variable, A,
    if  variable = WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.35533901
    {
         ;processing when text box was focused,
    }
    ; add "Else" clause here if you need
    return
```

This shows you the approach of detecting text box but:

- only some applications use Windows Forms technology and its TextBox (`WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.35533901`). For others, you will need to add different text box classes into the condition
- this is only draft showing how to test it, but it should give the idea

Comment: @Oleg – What do you mean by "again?". I use all browsers except Chrome so I cannot test it. :) Will Chrome return empty `variable` due to some incoherent GUI implemetation? I expected browsers like Chrome will adhere to standards. What is the result in Chrome? Thank you.

Comment: I meant our interaction few days ago in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651087/autohotkey-conflict-between-functions-using-the-same-key) question that started with me telling you your code won't work ;). Chrome doesn't use windows conrols. All of chrome is one control.

Comment: `ControlGetFocus, variable, A` always returns nothing when chrome is the active window.

Comment: @Oleg – Thank you for the input. Appreciated. I updated the answer.